# Calling a get name method for an object returns null

Tags: java, object, methods, null

I have a method that goes through each element in the ArrayList 'Clearance' and if it is an instance of HighClearance I want to add it to a String list of names.
Problem: Whenever I call the getName() method which is in the 'Clearance' superclass, it just returns null and dosent return the name.

```
public static String peopleClearance (ArrayList<Clearance> clearances) {
        String names = "";
    for(Clearance c: clearances) {
        if(c instanceof HighClearance) {
            System.out.println(c.getName()); //tested using sysout statement, just prints ''
            names += c.getName();
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

In the main method:

Note: The constructor in the Clearance class: public Clearance(String pname)

```
ArrayList<Clearance> clear= new ArrayList<Clearance>();
clear.add(new HighClearance("Mike"));
clear.add(new HighClearance("John"));
System.out.println(peopleClearance(clear));
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code from `Clearance` and `HighClearance`

Comment: Why does your the constructor in your Clearance class create a List of Clearance objects? That seems messy. Or is it just your formatting that is messy?

Comment: One of options is that you declared `name` field in both base and derived classes. Now your getter may be returning `name` from derived class while constructor may be initializing `name` in base class (or vice versa). But that is one of many mistakes you could have made, so if you want to know real reason post real code which will let us actually reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with this working example if your superclass/subclass is using the name property right:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Clearance> clearances = new ArrayList<>();
    clearances.add(new Clearance("C-Tes"));
    clearances.add(new HighClearance("H-Test"));
    clearances.add(new Clearance("CC-Test"));
    clearances.add(new HighClearance("HH-Test"));

    System.out.println(peopleClearance(clearances));
  }

  // changed the parameter to List interface instead of ArrayList
  public static String peopleClearance(List<Clearance> clearances) {
    String names = "";
    for (Clearance c : clearances) {
      if (c instanceof HighClearance) {
        System.out.println(c.getName()); // tested using sysout statement, just prints ''
        names += c.getName();
      }
    }
    return names;
  }
}

class Clearance {
  private String name;

  public Clearance(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}

class HighClearance extends Clearance {
   // if required!
  public HighClearance(String name) {
    super(name);
  }
}
```